# Explanation about variance on coin toss problem

Tags: probability

Consider an experiment where we toss a fair coin 100 times.

Let $X$ be the number of *tails* that are observed.

Let $Y$ be the number of *heads* that are observed and

let $Z = X + Y$

$$E(Y) = 100 × 0.5 = 50$$

$$ var(Y ) = 100 × 0.5 × 0.5 = 25$$

$$E(Z) = 50 + 50 = 100$$

$$var(Z) = 0 $$

Why is var(Z) = 0?

Why are Y and Z independent?

Comment: can $Z$ take any value other than $100$? if not, try and compute the variance of a set containing only 1 value (with as many repetitions as you like) - it had better turn out to be zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y$ and $Z$ are independent because $\Pr(Y=a\land Z=b)=\Pr(Y=a)\Pr(Z=b)$ for any $a$ and $b$. If $b=0$ they are both $0$, and if $b=100$ they are both $\Pr(Y=a)$.

As to variance of $Z$, we can even compute. By definition, $\text{Var}(Z)=E((100-E(Z))^2$.But $E(Z)=100$.